# Firebase cloud function http request to another firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a main firebase cloud function with main functionalities. But I need to create another one more specific that uses the functionalities on the main cloud function. Can I request a http Post or Get from one firebase cloud function to another firebase cloud function with a free account?

I tried to make it but I get the 'ENOTFOUND' message, I want to know if is something wrong with my code or it is just a limitation of the free account.

index.js

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
    var request = require('request')

    var options = {
      method: 'post',
      body: req.body, // re-send the incoming body to the main cloud function
      json: true, 
      url: '<main cloud url>',
      headers: req.headers // re-send the incoming headers the main cloud function
    }
    request(options, function (err, response, body) {
      if (err || response.statusCode != 200) {
        res.status(400).send(err); //re-send the received error to the client
        return
      }
      res.send(body); //re-send the received response to the client
    });
});

exports.checkAtivation = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: Edited to put the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's currently not possible on the Spark plan to invoke an HTTP Cloud Function from another HTTP Cloud Function.  You will have to upgrade to the Blaze plan.

It mostly doesn't make sense for one project's functions to invoke other functions over HTTP.  All the code in the project can be shared between all the functions if you simply abstract the logic away into a single function or module that all the endpoints can share.

Comment: This is exactly right; try calling your code internal to JavaScript, as opposed to making another HTTP call. However, I'll add that the Blaze plan has an even more generous free quota than the Spark plan does, so you could upgrade without it costing you anything.

Comment: @Doug - are there any tutorials on how to abstract functions into a  module?

Comment: I just got this error after never receiving it and only changing one line of code on a deployment. (that wasn't calling a firebase function via http)